# Nested dictionary append element through looping

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, append

In general, I created a dictionary with a code like:

```
dict = {}
if key not in dict:
    dict[key] = [element]
else:
    dict[key].append(element)
```

But if I want to apply a similar method to the nested dictionary, what should I do?
This is something I'm thinking, but of course, it did not work.

```
dict = {}
if key1, key2 not in dict:
    dict[key][key2] = [element]
else:
    dict[key][key2].append(element)
```

Comment: What is the `element` variable you are using?

Comment: @quamrana: That makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @quamrana. I edited the code a little bit. could be anything

Comment: Will an `and` not work in the `if` statement?

Comment: @leopardxpreload You will then have to resort to 4 branches since either key can be present or not. Using `setdefault` is the correct approach here

Comment: @DeepSpace - that makes sense - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
d = {}
d.setdefault('a', {}).setdefault('b', []).append('element')
print(d)
# {'a': {'b': ['element']}}
d.setdefault('a', {}).setdefault('b', []).append('another_element')
# {'a': {'b': ['element', 'another_element']}}
```

Comment: what if the element have separete list? like {'a': {'b':[['element1'], ['element2']]}}

Comment: @DonggyunKim Then append a list... `.append(['another_element'])`

Comment: @Deepsapce No I meant, every time, I append something, the separate two values will be added on two separate lists. {'a': {'b':['element_a1, element_a2, ...], [element_b1, element_b2, ...]]}}

Comment: @DonggyunKim You can't do that. This is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: Hmm ok. but I just tried this way, it seems working anyhow. Thanks.                dict.setdefault(key1, {}).setdefault(key2, [[],[]])[0].append(element1)
                dict.setdefault(key1, {}).setdefault(key2, [[],[]])[1].append(element2)